# How would one implement amazon ses SendRawEmail with attachments in php?

Tags: php, amazon-ses

I have started to use Amazon SES service for sending all my project e-mails.
Currently I have converted all my code to use it. But still lacking on examples for implementing e-mails with attachment as MIME types and HEADERS are not my strong side.

Could someone share some wisdom on how exactly I can get SendRawEmail to work? What 3rd-party libraries I should be using to create legit e-mail with attachments?

I use latest aws-ses-sdk for php.

Comment: I think the part about "spam" can not be specifically answered, but how to create a "raw" email can (spam scroring is more dependent on the actual message content then how you create the actual mail message technically).

Comment: @hakre Oh i see, so what im looking for is how to properly setup raw e-mail with proper headers and mime types.

Comment: Checkout http://swiftmailer.org/, you might implement a custom transport for aws-ses or you can just get the raw message from it.

Comment: @hakre yeah i was thinking about switfmailer, use it to compose a message with attachment then pass it in to SendRawEmail. Will SES accept the output of switftmailer? Well i guess they all work on standarts so it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions from hakre i found this swift mailer transport https://github.com/jmhobbs/Swiftmailer-Transport--AWS-SES and now i use swift mailer to handle all my e-mails with attachment and without directly to SES.

Comment: Can you please post your code to add an attachement. I am able to send email with it, but not sure how to send a file attachment.

Comment: @ Alexandre H. Tremblay just use it same as you would attach via swiftmailer. Look for documentation of swiftmailer.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to this other post here: [Sending email with attachment using amazon SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098285/sending-email-with-attachment-using-amazon-ses)

Rather than posting the answer again here, please see that post for the implementation that worked for me.