# how to send attachments in emails using AWS SES

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email programmatically using amazon's SES library using the code from [here](http://www.righthandedmonkey.com/2013/06/how-to-use-amazon-ses-to-send-email-php.html). After tweaking I have the following pieces of code.

SESUtils.php

```
<?php

require_once('aws.phar');

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

/**
 * SESUtils is a tool to make it easier to work with Amazon Simple Email Service
 * Features:
 * A client to prepare emails for use with sending attachments or not
 * 
 * There is no warranty - use this code at your own risk.  
 * @author sbossen 
 * http://right-handed-monkey.blogspot.com
 *
 * Update: Error checking and new params input array provided by Michael Deal
 */
class SESUtils {

const version = "1.0";
const AWS_KEY = SES_KEY;
const AWS_SEC = SES_SECRET;
const AWS_REGION = "us-east-1";
const MAX_ATTACHMENT_NAME_LEN = 60;

/**
 * Usage:
    $params = array(
      "to" => "email1@gmail.com",
      "subject" => "Some subject",
      "message" => "<strong>Some email body</strong>",
      "from" => "sender@verifiedbyaws",
      //OPTIONAL
      "replyTo" => "reply_to@gmail.com",
      //OPTIONAL
      "files" => array(
        1 => array(
           "name" => "filename1", 
          "filepath" => "/path/to/file1.txt", 
          "mime" => "application/octet-stream"
        ),
        2 => array(
           "name" => "filename2", 
          "filepath" => "/path/to/file2.txt", 
          "mime" => "application/octet-stream"
        ),
      )
    );

  $res = SESUtils::sendMail($params);

 * NOTE: When sending a single file, omit the key (ie. the '1 =>') 
 * or use 0 => array(...) - otherwise the file will come out garbled
 * 
 * use $res->success to check if it was successful
 * use $res->message_id to check later with Amazon for further processing
 * use $res->result_text to look for error text if the task was not successful
 * 
 * @param array $params - array of parameters for the email
 * @return \ResultHelper
 */
public static function sendMail($params) {

    $to = self::getParam($params, 'to', true);
    $subject = self::getParam($params, 'subject', true);
    $body = self::getParam($params, 'message', true);
    $from = self::getParam($params, 'from', true);
    $replyTo = self::getParam($params, 'replyTo');
    $files = self::getParam($params, 'files');

    $res = new ResultHelper();

    // get the client ready
    $client = SesClient::factory(array(
        'key' => self::AWS_KEY,
        'secret' => self::AWS_SEC,
        'region' => self::AWS_REGION
    ));

    // build the message
    if (is_array($to)) {
        $to_str = rtrim(implode(',', $to), ',');
    } else {
        $to_str = $to;
    }

    $msg = "To: $to_str\n";
    $msg .= "From: $from\n";

    if ($replyTo) {
        $msg .= "Reply-To: $replyTo\n";
    }

    // in case you have funny characters in the subject
    $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, 'UTF-8');
    $msg .= "Subject: $subject\n";
    $msg .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n";
    $boundary = uniqid("_Part_".time(), true); //random unique string
    $msg .= " boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";
    $msg .= "\n";

    // now the actual message
    $msg .= "--$boundary\n";

    // first, the plain text
    $msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
    $msg .= "\n";
    $msg .= strip_tags($body);
    $msg .= "\n";

    // now, the html text
    $msg .= "--$boundary\n";
    $msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
    $msg .= "\n";
    $msg .= $body;
    $msg .= "\n";

    // add attachments
    if (is_array($files)) {
        $count = count($files);
        foreach ($files as $idx => $file) {
            if ($idx !== 0)
                $msg .= "\n";
            $msg .= "--$boundary\n";
            $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
            $clean_filename = mb_substr($file["name"], 0, self::MAX_ATTACHMENT_NAME_LEN);
            $msg .= "Content-Type: {$file['mime']}; name=$clean_filename;\n";
            $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$clean_filename;\n";
            $msg .= "\n";
            $msg .= base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['filepath']));
            if (($idx + 1) === $count)
                $msg .= "==\n";
            $msg .= "--$boundary";
        }
        // close email
        $msg .= "--\n";
    }

    // now send the email out
    try {
        file_put_contents("log.txt", $msg);
        $ses_result = $client->sendRawEmail(
                array(
            'RawMessage' => array(
                'Data' => base64_encode($msg)
            )
                ), array(
            'Source' => $from,
            'Destinations' => $to_str
                )
        );
        if ($ses_result) {
            $res->message_id = $ses_result->get('MessageId');
        } else {
            $res->success = false;
            $res->result_text = "Amazon SES did not return a MessageId";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $res->success = false;
        $res->result_text = $e->getMessage().
                " - To: $to_str, Sender: $from, Subject: $subject";
    }
    return $res;
}

private static function getParam($params, $param, $required = false) {
    $value = isset($params[$param]) ? $params[$param] : null;
    if ($required && empty($value)) {
        throw new Exception('"'.$param.'" parameter is required.');
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}

}

class ResultHelper {

    public $success = true;
    public $result_text = "";
    public $message_id = "";

}

?>
```

And the function I'm using to send the actual email

```
function sendAttachmentEmail($from, $to, $subject, $message, $attachmentPaths=array()){
    client = SesClient::factor(array('key' => SES_KEY, 'secret' => SES_SECRET, 'region' => 'us-east-1'));
    $attachments = array();
    foreach($attachmentPaths as $path){
        $fileName = explode("/",, $path);
        $fileName = $fileName[count($fileName)-1];
        $extension = explode(".", $fileName);
        $extension = strtoupper($extension[count($extension)-1]);
        $mimeType = "";
        if($extension == 'PDF') $mimeType = 'application/pdf';
        elseif($extension == 'CSV') $mimeType = 'test/csv';
        elseif($extension == 'XLS') $mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        array_push($attachments, array("name" => $fileName, "filepath" => $path, "mime" => $mimeType));
    }
    $params = array(
        "from" => $from,
        "to" => $to,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "message" => $message,
        "replyTo" => $from,
        "files" => $attachments
    );
    $res = SESUtils::sendMail($params);
    return $res;
}

sendAttachmentEmail("jesse@aol.com", "jesse@aol.com", 'test', 'test', array("/path/to/file.pdf"));
```

When I run this the message returned is an error saying `"Expected ';', got "Reports" - To: jesse@aol.com, Sender: jesse@aol.com, Subject: test"`. Anyone know what I might be missing? The contents of the msg being sent is

```
To: jesse@aol.com
From: jesse@aol.com
Reply-To: jesse@aol.com
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_Part_142255491754ca7725b0bf89.40746157"

--_Part_142255491754ca7725b0bf89.40746157
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test
--_Part_142255491754ca7725b0bf89.40746157
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test
--_Part_142255491754ca7725b0bf89.40746157
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=file.pdf;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098285/sending-email-with-attachment-using-amazon-ses

here is your answer

Comment: that's where i found the code in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Late but i hope this could help others.

The best way to achieve this goal is using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to compose the email and get the **MIMEMessage** to pass it as **RawMessage** to **AWS SES client**.

---

Installation with composer:

```
$ composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

---

PHPMailer naive example:

```php
// Create PHPMailer instance
$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

// Set the email values
$mail->setFrom("foo@bar.com", "Jhon Doe");
$mail->addAddress("destination@somedomain.com");
$mail->Subject = "Hi There ! ";
$mail->Body = <<<EOS
Your email content, <br>
you can write it even as a <strong>HTML document</strong>
EOS;
$mail->AltBody = <<<EOS
Your email content, here you write plain text body for clients that do not support html.
EOS;

// Here you attach your file or files
// @string path
// @string file_name. If not specified, it takes the original name from the path.
$mail->addAttachment("/path/to/file.xlsx", 'my_file.xlsx');

// Here is the magic
$mail->preSend();
$rawMessage = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
```

---

Now, you can pass the MIMEMessage to the sendRawEmail method in the SES SDK

```php
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYYYY');
$ses_client = new Aws\Ses\SesClient([
        'credentials' => $credentials,
        'version' => '2010-12-01',
        'region'  => 'us-west-2'
]);


$ses_client->sendRawEmail([
            "RawMessage" => [
                "Data" => $rawMessage
            ]
]);
```

That's it !

Comment: This worked great with one change. I had to add `$mail->preSend();` right before the call to `getSentMIMEMessage`. Thanks!

Comment: Official sample code of phpmailer and aws php sdk: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-ses-Send_Raw_Email.php.html

Answer (score 5):

Here is my working solution for PHP 7 using V3.x of AWS PHP SDK.
This solution will send a HTML mail with one attachment:

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

$gAWS_SES_client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'my_secret_key',
        'secret'  => 'my_secret_pw'
  ) 
));



function sendRAWEmailViaSES($myArrayToAdresses, $myFromAdress, $mySubject, $myHTMLBody, $myFilePath){
    global $gAWS_SES_client;

    echo "\n<BR>Now in sendRAWEmailViaSES()<BR>\n";

    $myStringToAddresses = implode(",", $myArrayToAdresses);

    $myFileName = basename($myFilePath);;

    $myDataAttachedFile = file_get_contents($myFilePath);
    $myDataAttachedFile = chunk_split(base64_encode($myDataAttachedFile));  

    $myFileMimeInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $myFileMimeType = finfo_file($myFileMimeInfo, $myFilePath);     

    $mySeparator = md5(time());
    $mySeparator_multipart = md5($mySubject . time());      

    $myMessage = "";

    $myMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

    $myMessage .= "To: ".$myStringToAddresses."\n"; 
    $myMessage .= "From:".$myFromAdress."\n";   
    $myMessage .= "Subject:".$mySubject."\n";

    $myMessage .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$mySeparator_multipart."\"\n";
    $myMessage .= "\n--".$mySeparator_multipart."\n";

    $myMessage .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$mySeparator."\"\n";
    $myMessage .= "\n--".$mySeparator."\n";

    $myMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
    $myMessage .= "\n".$myHTMLBody."\n";
    $myMessage .= "\n--".$mySeparator."--\n";

    $myMessage .= "--".$mySeparator_multipart."\n";
    $myMessage .= "Content-Type: ".$myFileMimeType."; name=\"".$myFileName."\"\n";
    $myMessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$myFileName."\"\n";
    $myMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
    $myMessage .= $myDataAttachedFile."\n";
    $myMessage .= "--".$mySeparator_multipart."--";

    //echo "\n<BR>Message:<BR>\n";
    //print_r($myMessage);
    //echo "<BR>\n";        


    $myArraySES = [
        'Source'       => $myFromAdress,
        'Destinations' => $myArrayToAdresses,
        'RawMessage'   => [
            'Data' => $myMessage
        ]
    ];  

    echo "\n<HR>Trying to send mail via AAWS SES <BR>\n";


    try{
        $myResult = true;
        $myAPIResult = $gAWS_SES_client->sendRawEmail($myArraySES);

        //save the MessageId which can be used to track the request
        //$myMessageArrayID = $myAPIResult->get('MessageId');
        //echo("MessageId: $msg_id");

        //view sample output
        echo "\n<BR>SES Result:<BR>\n";
        print_r($myAPIResult);
        echo "<BR>\n";

    } catch (Exception $myObjError) {
        //An error happened and the email did not get sent
        $myErrorInfo = $myObjError->getMessage();

        echo "\n<BR>*** SES ERROR:<BR>\n";
        print_r($myErrorInfo);
        echo "<BR>\n";      

        $myfile = fopen("ses_send_error.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, $myErrorInfo);
        fclose($myfile);

    }   


}
```