# For AWS SES boto3 what type of attachment is the documentation referring to for the send_email function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

In the boto 3 reference docs under the send_email function its says, "The total size of the message, including attachments, must be smaller than 10 MB."

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email

I am trying to attach a csv file to an email.  All the examples I have seen online use send_raw_email.  But this statement under send_email makes me think its possible to attach a csv with the send_email function.  What type of attachment is the boto 3 reference docs referring to under the send_email function?  Can you add an attachment like a csv or a pdf to a message and send it out via send_email?

Comment: what do you mean by _what type of attachment_

Comment: Are they referring to the text part of the multipart email as an attachment here - I feel like that's a basic part of multipart and not considered an attachment.  By type of attachment, I mean can you attach a pdf, a csv, or a word doc for example?

Comment: @RightHandedMonkey Do you think could add some color around why the boto 3 docs refer to attachments for the send_email function?  I saw your similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098285/sending-email-with-attachment-using-amazon-ses?rq=1